# Do we lie ON the bed or IN the bed?

Tags: prepositions

When people take a rest **in/on** the bed, do they lie **ON** or **IN** the bed?

(In my native language both are optional)

[image]

Comment: If **sleep** and **lie** are the same (I don't know) then it's a duplicate. But as a non native English speaker I don't have the knowledge to say it confidently (that lie equals to sleep)

Comment: I believe the on/in distinction holds true for a few different verbs, to include lie vs sleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> on a bed

[image]

on top of the bed and its bedding.

> in a bed
>   in bed

[image]
<sub>(source: [mirror.co.uk](http://i1.mirror.co.uk/incoming/article7778212.ece/ALTERNATES/s615b/Woman-asleep-in-bed.jpg))</sub>

surrounded but the bed and its bedding.

Answer (score 3):

If you lie on top of the sheets, duvet, etc, then you are **on** the bed. If you get under the sheets, then you are **in** bed, and you can lie in bed, stay in bed, read in bed, sleep in bed, and do all those other lovely things "in bed" as you please.

Answer (score 1):

To lie on the bed.

To lie in bed.

To lie in the bed.

All the phrases  are grammatical, with a difference in meaning.

You use the phrase "on the bed" when somebody is not covered with sheets or blankets.  For example:

He lay on the bed (=on top of the covers).

You use the phrase "in bed" when somebody is covered with sheets or blankets. For example:

He lay in bed (=under covers).

You use the phrase "in the bed" when you are referring to a particular bed. For example:

There was no one in the bed (Longman Dictionary).

Comment: What you say is true from an idiomatic perspective; however, from a technical standpoint, if you are _in_ a bed, you are by default _on_ the bed.

Comment: Sorry, downvoting for conflating lie & lay since this for English language learners.